# Trying to hide API Key using another JS file, but it prevents API from working properly

Tags: api, api-key

when I had API key info on the main script, fetching API data was working properly. But when I try to hide API key using config.js file. It stops working. Does anyone know what is the problem? (*red highlighted boxes on the images are only difference after hiding API key)

[image: Config that has API Key]

[image: Script file that is trying to hide API Key]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most appropriate approach is using the .env file or environment variable to hide your API key.

For more details -
[How to use .env file](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/heres-how-you-can-actually-use-node-environment-variables-8fdf98f53a0a/)